# Google Script getElementById from GUI to edit

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I have one TextBox (named BoxUser) and a PasswordBox (BoxPAssword) with value Password (***************) in the GUI which i have created

Now i want to edit BoxPassword field value to: " " when a user write his own password to access the application.

I thought about using clickservers...

this code should work but doesnt

My handlers works right(serverHandler to clear_pass) + "Name of panel"

Please help!.

---

```
function doGet(){

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Panel de acceso");

  var Panel = app.loadComponent("Acceso");

  app.add(Panel);

 return app;

};


**function clear_pass(e){**

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var Panel = app.loadComponent("Acceso");

  var BoxPassword = app.getElementById("BoxPassword");

  BoxPassword.setText("");

  app.add(Panel);

  return app;

};
```

Comment: Anyone can answer me? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

> Well, nobody has answered me during these hours. I've been working on
>   it and I've found a solution without using GUI.

---

```
function doGet(){

var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Panel de acceso");

  /*var Panel = app.loadComponent("Acceso");

  app.add(Panel);*/

  var absolutePanel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setId("apbsolutePanel");

  var mainPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("mainPanel");

  var lbUser = app.createLabel("Usuario: ");

  var textBoxUser = app.createTextBox().setId("textBoxUser").setName("textBoxUser");

  var lbPass = app.createLabel("Password: ");

  var textBoxPass =app.createPasswordTextBox().setId("textBoxPass").setName("textBoxPass");

  var boton = app.createButton().setText("Entrar");



  var handlerClear = app.createServerHandler("clear_pass").addCallbackElement(textBoxPass);

  textBoxPass.addClickHandler(handlerClear);


  mainPanel.add(lbUser);

  mainPanel.add(textBoxUser);

  mainPanel.add(lbPass);

  mainPanel.add(textBoxPass);

  mainPanel.add(boton);

  absolutePanel.add(mainPanel);

  app.add(absolutePanel);

  return app;

};
```

---

```
function clear_pass(e){

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var textBoxPass = app.getElementById("textBoxPass");

  textBoxPass.setText("");

  return app;

};
```

Comment: the problem was that your question was not easy to answer because when using the GUI the handlers are defined in the GUI itself, not in the code and therefore it was impossible to know if they where correctly implemented (widget name, callbackelement, function name). You could have kept the GUI design and set the handler in the code just as you did